# Strange voltage in analog input pin

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm working with a custom board which uses a SMT32L462CEU6TR MCU. For power saving purposes I've set all pins in analog mode and entered STOP2 mode. Doing that, I've got an strange current consumption.

On PB3 pin, which I use to act on a power load switch, I've 1.8 V, which for doesn't make sense. PB3 is the SWO pin as well. Is there any configuration to solve this?

This is main.c I'm using:

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      /* Insert 5 second delay */
          HAL_Delay(5000);

          /* Set all GPIO in analog state to reduce power consumption,
             except GPIOC to keep user button interrupt enabled */
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();

          GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
          GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_All;

          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStruct);
          HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);

          __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_DISABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_DISABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_DISABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_DISABLE();
          __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_DISABLE();


          /* Enter STOP 2 mode */
          HAL_PWREx_EnterSTOP2Mode(PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);

          RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
           RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
           uint32_t pFLatency = 0;

           /* Enable Power Control clock */
           __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

           /* Get the Oscillators configuration according to the internal RCC registers */
           HAL_RCC_GetOscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

           /* Enable PLL */
           RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_NONE;
           RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
           if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
           {
             Error_Handler();
           }

           /* Get the Clocks configuration according to the internal RCC registers */
           HAL_RCC_GetClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, &pFLatency);

           /* Select PLL as system clock source and keep HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 clocks dividers as before */
           RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType     = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK;
           RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource  = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
           if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, pFLatency) != HAL_OK)
           {
             Error_Handler();
           }
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSIState = RCC_LSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief RTC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 1 */

  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN RTC_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END RTC_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PC13 PC14 PC15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PH0 PH1 PH3 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_3;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOH, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA0 PA1 PA2 PA3
                           PA4 PA5 PA6 PA7
                           PA8 PA9 PA10 PA11
                           PA12 PA13 PA14 PA15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3
                          |GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7
                          |GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11
                          |GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB0 PB1 PB2 PB10
                           PB11 PB12 PB13 PB14
                           PB15 PB3 PB4 PB5
                           PB6 PB7 PB8 PB9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_10
                          |GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13|GPIO_PIN_14
                          |GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5
                          |GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7|GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a software problem? It's pretty common to have external resistors on the SWD signals to protect against ESD.

Comment: I've the same hardware configuration in a few pins on this same MCU and there is no voltage drop on them. I' ve disabled SWD on the MX, and put it as analog pins. Souldn't  it work as the other regular pins do? Thanks!